# How to change absolute path of reference in Maya?

Tags: reference, maya

I have a lot of small Maya files that have reference rig files. When changing the hard drive letter E to D for example, all Maya files start to search file from last driver file which now does not work. I have to manually specify the new path of the rig in each file. And so I would like to know, whether it's possible to register the path of these rigs through Maya.env or something else?
something like E\Job\Robot1_rig.ma = D\Job\Robot1_rig.ma in Maya.env

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't register replacement paths. But there are some other options to deal with such situations:

1. If your animation files are Maya ASCII, it's possible to replace paths just by searching and replacing the respective texts inside them.
2. If you plan to switch locations in advance, you can use the environment variables. Maya expands environment variables in paths automatically. For example, instead of specifying `E:\Job\Robot1_rig.ma` define an environment variable `ROBOT_RIG_DIR=E:\Job` and then import your reference as `$ROBOT_RIG_DIR\Robot1_rig.ma` (you'll see the expanded path in the reference editor under "Resolved name"). Then if you change your mind later you can redefine the environment variable.